# How to solve $6x^{2/3}-12-2x=0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, cubics

How to solve  $6x^{2/3}-12-2x=0$? I need it to prove that the graphic of $y=6x^{2/3}$ never meets the graphic of function $y=12+2x$.

Comment: Let $t:=x^{1/3}$ and solve $6t^2-12-2t^3=0$?  Surely, there is a real solution.

Comment: Since you are new, you might find the tips given [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) to ask good questions useful. In particular, you will get more efficient help if you tell us what you've tried, where exactly you got stuck, where you found this problem/ exercise, perhaps what is your mathematical level...

Comment: There is one solution $x=-1.71001957946154131046273081535...$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $t=x^{1/3}$, the equation is
$$
t^3-3t^2+6=0
$$
The only real root of this equation is negative. Indeed the derivative of $f(t)=t^3-3t^2+6$ is $f'(t)=3(t^2-2)$, that vanishes at $t=-\sqrt{2}$ and $t=\sqrt{2}$. Since
$$
f(-\sqrt{2})=-2\sqrt{2}<0
\qquad
f(\sqrt{2})=2\sqrt{2}>0
$$
the polynomial has a single real root, which is negative because $f(0)=6>0$.

Thus the curve $y=x^{2/3}$ and the line $y=12+2x$ intersect at a point with $x<0$.

[image]

If you consider $x^{2/3}$ only defined for $x\ge0$, then you're right, there is no intersection.

Answer (score 0):

We have $x+6 = 3x^{2/3}$ i.e $(x+6)^3 = 27x^2$. This has a real solution. You won't be able to prove what you wish.

Answer (score 0):

We have $6^3x^{2}=(12+2x)^3$. Use the Cardamo formula for cubic equation.

Answer (score -1):

Let $x^{\frac{1}{3}}=y$.

Thus, $x>0$, $y>0$ and we need to solve
$$y^3-3y^2+6=0.$$ 
But, by AM-GM
$$y^3+6=2\left(\frac{y^3}{2}\right)+6\geq3\sqrt[3]{6\left(\frac{y^3}{2}\right)^2}>3y^2,$$ which says that our equation has no real roots.

Comment: You're using $12/2=4$.

Comment: @egreg Thank you! I fixed.

Comment: The substitution you used is $y = x^{1/3}$ , so your bounds are wrong.

Comment: @NickD It was typo. I fixed. Actually, if we wrote $x^{\frac{1}{3}}$ so $x>0$ by definition. If we wrote $\sqrt[3]x$ so a value of $x$ can be any real number.

Comment: The cube root of -8 is -2, so no: $x > 0$ is wrong.

Comment: @NickD It depends on definition. $\sqrt[3]{-8}=-2$, but $(-8)^{\frac{1}{3}}$ it's absurd. These things they are well if we want to work with function $f(x)=x^{\alpha}$, where $\alpha\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: There is nothing absurd about it: it's the unique number whose cube is -8. $y=x^3$ is a bijective function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$, so its inverse exists everywhere. That inverse is the cube root, whether you write it as $\sqrt[3]{x}$ or as $x^{1/3}$.

Comment: BTW, instead of insisting, have you looked at the other answers?

Comment: @NickD I saw and I think that my solution is an unique right here. I think, I explained, why I think so. Another argument. What do you think about the value $(-8)^{\frac{2}{6}}$?